# How to improve a poisson based estimator using variance reduction techniques

Tags: estimation

Given a random number $X \sim Pois(\mu)$ for some random, i.i.d $\mu$, I'm trying to estimate $P(X \ge x)$ by simulation. The approach is to use a raw/classic estimator, where I generate a bunch of $X$, by first generating an equally large number of $\mu$ and the counting the amount of $X \ge c$ finding the mean of 
$$I(x) = \left \{
    \begin{array}
     .  x < c, & 0\\
       x \ge c, & 1
    \end{array}
\right .
$$

$\mu$ is a random number with a density function on the form of $f(x) = \frac{c_1}{c_2 + g(x)}$ for $x \in (0, 1)$, where $g(x)$ is a monotone, decreasing, non-linear function.

I'm trying to find out how to improve the estimator using a few different techniques, namely importance sampling, conditioning, control variate and antithetic variables, but I'm having little luck in fully grasping how to do this.

Since $P(X \ge c)$ is *highly* unlikely to occur, I have had to generate a huge amount of random values to get an estimate, and have estimating the value using more than $10^{9}$ samples, where the results always gave (roughly) the same estimate, in the order of $10^{-6}$, with an identical variance.

I haven't gotten around to do importance sampling yet, so just ignore that for the moment (I'm not asking for the solution, just pointers to figure out 
what I'm doing wrong).

## Conditioning

Since it's possible to calcuate $P(X \ge c)$ for a known $\mu$, I've tried doing that directly for a set of $\mu$; this yields the same estimate as the raw estimator and greatly improveces the variance to an order of $10^{-12}$, from the raw $10^{-6}$. This feels a bit like cheating though and I'm not entirely convinced that this is actually using conditioning.

## Failing to use control variates

Like with antithetic variables, I haven't managed to successfully implement control variates. I've tried using two approaches:

- Generating $U_1 \sim U(0,1)$ to calcuate the means $\mu$ based on $U_1$ and then generate a sample of $X$ based on the means. I then generate $U_2$ and use that to generate $Y$ distributed on $N(0,1)$ with a standard deviation based on $U_2$.
- As above, but instead of using $U_2$ to generate $Y$, use $U_1$
- As both of the above, but swapping $N$ with some other distribution.

The estimate is then based on $X + c (Y - E[Y])$ with  $c = - \frac{cov(X,Y)}{var(Y)}$.
Using these methods, I either get an estimate that's identical to the raw estimator but no improvement in variance, or I get something that's in the order of $10^{-4}$ or $10^{-12}$.

I need to use this on both the conditioned estimator and the raw estimator.

## Failing to use antithetic variables

My approach for using antithetic variable is to generate $U \sim U(0,1)$ and then calculate $Y_1$, using $U$ and $Y_2$ using $1 - U$ -- i.e. $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are clearly negatively correlated and both distributed on $U(0,1)$. I've then tried to approaches to get an estimate:

- Generate $X_1$ using $Y_1$ and $X_2$ using $Y_2$ and finding the mean of the estimators based on $X_1$ and $X_2$
- Generate $X_1$ using $\frac{Y_1 + Y_2}{2}$ and use $X_1$ to find the estimate.

Using both methods I always get an estimator which is only $\frac{3}{5}$ of what the raw estimator gives me. Clearly not correct.

This only needs to be done for the conditioned estimator and not for the raw estimator.